# NUnit with Specflow: SetUpAttribute attribute not allowed in a SetUpFixture

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, specflow

I upgraded my Nunit to 3.0 from 2.6 and now all of my Unit Tests are failing with the following error:

OneTimeSetUp: SetUpAttribute attribute not allowed in a SetUpFixture

I read through the NUnit documentation and found that there are some "breaking changes" with the new release and I can no longer use a "SetUpAttribute" inside a "SetUpFixture".

I will have to replace this with "OneTimeSetUpAttribute" and I would but my MAIN problem is that my Nunit test fixtures are generated by Specflow.

I have specflow 2.1 and this is generating test fixtures with default "OneTimeSetUpAttribute" regardless of Nunit version.

Did anyone else come across this problem and have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we did some work in the 2.2 version for the used attributes. Could you try the latest package from our CI-feed? https://ci.appveyor.com/nuget/specflow-ci

Comment: Thanks @AndreasWillich but I am not able to find this version in Nuget Package Manager.

Comment: You have to add the feed url he gave you to your package sources in VS.

Comment: @AndreasWillich Do you guys generate SetUpFixtures? I've only seen TestFixtures in repros of problems people send me.